# How to set global array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript function, similar to

```
function ColorListPicker(listLength) {
    var colorCodeArray = ["#046c93", "#4caf50", "#8bc34a", "#cddc39", "#00bcd4", "#009688", "#e91e63", "#673ab7", "#ff9800", "#9e9e9e", "#f3f3f3"];
    var colorList = "[";
    for (var i = 0; i < listLength; i++) {
        colorList = colorList + '"' + colorCodeArray[i] + '",';
    }
    var colorListData = colorList.substr(0, colorList.length – 1);
    colorListData = colorListData + "]";
    return colorListData;
}
```

If I call this function normally, like `var colorList = ColorListPicker(5);`, then the `colorList` variable is set to the return value, as though I had done `colorList=["#046c93", "#4caf50", "#8bc34a", "#cddc39", "#00bcd4"]`.

But I want to declare `colorCodeArray` to be a global and use it from my `ColorListPicker` function.

How can I make `ColorListPicker` set a global variable, instead of returning a value?

Comment: If you want it to be global, just declare it as global. Move it outside of any functions and you're good.

Comment: are you sure it's returning an array? It seems you're building a string

Comment: @ArifulHaque, what are you actually trying to build? Your code doesn't make much sense, it's just a complicated way to `return JSON.stringify(colorCodeArray.slice(0, listLength))`. Do you really want a JSON-string? In this case, the function-name should reflect that in some way.

Answer (score 2):

> But now i want to declare colorCodeArray variable global and use it from my ColorListPicker function.

Just extract the array into a global variable and use it within the function:

```
var colorCodeArray = ["#046c93", "#4caf50", "#8bc34a", "#cddc39", "#00bcd4", "#009688", "#e91e63", "#673ab7", "#ff9800", "#9e9e9e", "#f3f3f3"];  

function ColorListPicker(listLength) {

  // use colorCodeArray within the function

}
```

Related question: [What is the scope of variables in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascrip)

Check out [the answer by Rion Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37035412/3928341) for other useful suggestions on improving your function

Answer (score 1):

**Determining the Proper Scope**

Just consider declaring your `colorCodeArray` variable outside the scope of your `ColorListPicker()` function, which would make it function as a global variable :

```
// Now colorCodeArray should be accessible from anywhere you need it
var colorCodeArray = ["#046c93", "#4caf50", "#8bc34a", "#cddc39", "#00bcd4", "#009688", "#e91e63", "#673ab7", "#ff9800", "#9e9e9e", "#f3f3f3"];  

// Define your function here
function ColorListPicker(listLength){
    // Your code here
}
```

**Consider Using `slice()` Instead Of A Loop**

Additionally, it looks like you are attempting to retrieve the first N elements of your array. If that is the case, you could consider using the [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function which does just that :

```
function ColorListPicker(listLength){
     // This would return the first N elements from your global array
     return colorCodeArray.slice(0,listLength);
}
```

**Or use `join()` if you want to build a string...**

or if you wanted to explicitly wrap the result in square braces, you could use the [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) function to merge the elements of an array into a string using a specific delimiter :

```
function ColorListPickerAsString(listLength){
    // This would return "['#046c93','#4caf50','#8bc34a','#cddc39','#00bcd4']"
    return '[\'' + colorCodeArray.slice(0,listLength).join('\',\'') + '\']';
}
```

**Example**

You can [see an example of both of these options here](http://jsbin.com/jemago/edit?js) and demonstrated below :

[image]